# Retrieve a Google account's email address or other information from a profile photo

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-contacts

I recently saw some very strange behavior in drive, [similar to what's outlined here](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/87658395/an-item-was-automatically-placed-in-without-my-permission?hl=en&msgid=108546470), and the only information we have on the user is their profile photo and URL. In the activity pane, you can see that a user photo had an item "automatically placed in" some location, but the user's name does not appear as it usually does.

[image]

A reverse image search turned up nothing. Is there any other way to find the Google account given only the profile photo URL so we can try to find out who did this or what happened?

As an example, my profile link looks like this: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADea4I74hGrL9ZRco9BY_UG1I7d2oIReaSZgiV3HRKCj138=s83

Comment: While include links to external content might be helpful, questions having them still should be self-contained, so please add a brief summary of the linked content..

Comment: I added an example of my profile link to show what I'm talking about

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "who did this or what happened"

Comment: Ah sorry, added some more context in the question